# Explicit formula of a fundamental matrix

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, fundamental-solution

I'm trying to solve the following differential system explicitly
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
y \\ 
z%
\end{array}%
\right) ^{\prime }=\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & b(t) \\ 
\delta b(t) & a(t)%
\end{array}%
\right) \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
y \\ 
z%
\end{array}%
\right) ,\text{ }\delta \in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
$$
Can we find an explicit formula of the solutions?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The matrix equation $$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = A(t) \mathbf{x}$$ has solution

$$\displaystyle  \mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{x}(0) e^{\int_0^t A(\tau) d\tau}. $$

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} y\\z \end{pmatrix}, \quad e^{\int_0^\tau A d\tau} = I + \int_0^t d\tau \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b(t) \\ \delta b(t) & a(t) \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2!} \left\{  \int_0^t d\tau \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b(t) \\ \delta b(t) & a(t) \end{pmatrix} \right\}^2 + \cdots$$

You can compute the elements of $\mathbf{x}(t)$ by summing the series.

Comment: It doesn't work like that for non-autonomuous systems.

Comment: What doesn't work like what?

Comment: The expression seems to satisfy the equation, no?